# Akka: Not valid URI

Tags: scala, akka

I am using

```
akka.http.scaladsl.model.Uri
```

for the following url/GET:

http://localhost:8000/some-service/getSomething?param={"name":"john","street":"SOMEWHERE STREET","surname":"smith"}

(yes the `json` is in a `get/query` param)

but I am getting:

```
akka.http.scaladsl.model.IllegalUriException: Illegal URI reference: Invalid input ' ', expected raw-query-char, '#' or 'EOI'
```

I cannot get what is wrong with that URL. I am reading the used RFC spec here:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.1

but still I can't figure it out. Any help?

Comment: It tells you exactly which character is wrong.

Comment: You need to url encode that json

Comment: It would be simple here to post a complete code example, you are possibly not using the .withQuery properly.

Comment: the caracter position it refers is the space in "SOMEWHERE STREET". I am not expecting it wants %20

Comment: "I am not expecting it wants %20". That's a problem, then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, you need to url endode that json so that the complete url, with query params, is valid according to the RFC spec.  First, let's show what's broken again.  Consider that you have this code:

```
val json = """{"foo":"some foo"}"""
val baseUri = "http://some.host.com:8080/test" 

val akkaUri = Uri(s"$baseUri/?json=$json")
```

This is one way to build an Akka `Uri`, but this way will be broken and throw an exception as the query param is not properly encoded.  If you change your code to this instead, then things will work:

```
val akkaUri = Uri(baseUri).withQuery(Uri.Query(Map("json" -> json)))
```

By using `withQuery`, you allow the Akka Http framework properly url encode the params, which won't happen if you just construct the `Uri` from the complete uri string